# Is it possible to send mail using Java when gmail access is blocked

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have working code to send mail using gmail smtp. It's working on my machine, but when I'm trying to run same code from my office system, then it showing error **Unable to Connect SMTP Server**. So, I was wondering, is it possible to send mail by bye-passing local/office network ? Any work-around ?

PS: I can't use my corporate email address, since it's internal task.

Comment: It will most probably be impossible to bypass this security unless it is very poor quality... but your company maybe offers a smtp server for u to use for that kind of tasks ?

Comment: have you tried using `mailutils`?

Comment: @Bartdude.. I could have used, but there are many reason : 1. We need to change password every 30-40 days, means need to update same password again in code. 2. Exposure of password to someone else.

Comment: In the past, we have asked IT to create an account to be used exclusively for and by the application.  The account would have its own credentials, no access to anything else in the network but the smtp mailbox it sends to and it is also exempt of password expiration policies.  Maybe that would be better than letting google read your email (what if that account gets hacked?, who would be responsible?) - Sounds like a trouble-prone workaround from a security stand point...

Comment: You should edit the Subject of your question. Sending email using java has nothing to do with Gmail

Comment: As others have suggested, the best approach is to use your corporate mail server.  If that's not possible, you may be able to configure JavaMail to [work through your corporate proxy server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is install a mail server on your machine and use that mail server to send emails. There are a lot of opensource and/or free options available. I have used [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/) in the past (on Windows7), and it seemed to work for me, just the way I wanted it to. One possible downside of using this approach is that your emails may sometimes end up in the spam folders of your intended recipients.

However, you will need Administrator privileges to install most mailservers.